# How is the Generator Matrix of the Hamming Code remodeled to a diffrent shape

Tags: math, computer-science, hamming-code

How originated the lower Generator Matrix from the standard Generatormatrix of the Hamming Code?

Standard Generatormatrix of the Hamming Code with the Partity bits at the end:
[Stardard Generatormatrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLNZX.png)

Diffrent Generatormatrix, so that you have the parity bits at position 1,2 and 4
[remodeled Generator Matrix of the Hamming Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zk3c.png)

I tried to find the souloution myself but i did not